# What are these types of textures?

Tags: texturing

I was looking through some models I download and found the some textures I didn't recognize:

-albedotint

-exponent

-cubemap

-gold

-metal

-lightwarp

Are these types of textures useable in Blender? (The models were originally in SFM format, that's why I ask).